# Facebook open graph protocol: how can I reach the scattered audience of people who liked individual pages on my website?

Tags: facebook

If you add Open Graph Protocol metadata to your website that is different for every URL (so the url in

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourwebsite.com/somepage.html">
```

is the url of the page itself), you end up with an unmanageable number of "virtual" fan pages.  I don't see a way to post updates to (newsfeeds of ) the fans of those individual pages all at once... Do you know of any "sitewide" update possibility?

The alternative is that you set the URL parameter in the og metadata to a constant url - either your homepage or a "traditional" Facebook Fan page.  This has the disadvantage however that if people like an individual posting on your site, in their newsfeed it shows up as a like of your homepage or Facebook fan page, and the link their friends see is their homepage or their individual fan page - a behaviour that seems illogical to most people and can be perceived as spammy.

Anyone found a good solution for this conundrum?

(BTW cross-posted this on Quora http://www.quora.com/Facebook-open-graph-protocol-how-can-I-reach-the-scattered-audience-of-people-who-liked-individual-pages-on-my-website )

PS: I tried to add the tags facebook-pages open-graph-protocol to this question, but lack the required reputation of 300 - maybe someone else can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do you have a list of all of your pages that have been liked? Maybe stored in your db?
2. If not, can you export it from facebook.com/insights > your site ?
3. Take the list of URLs, then loop through, sending a message to the Likers of each page using the sample code found here (watch out for duplicates):
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#publishing

Comment: Thx for pointing to that resource. I was hoping there would be a way to do it without iterating over the pages or without doing it programmatically.  I meanwhile found a Wordpress plugin that helps publishing updates to people who have liked your pages where you can actually list the IDs of those pages: see 3d screenshot at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/like/screenshots/ BTW the process consists of iterating over pages you publish a message on (that will appear in the newsfeed of the users), AFAIK there's no way to iterate over the individual users (as opposed to the "old" fan pages)